# How to acces attribute of this html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access an attribute (`aria-controls`) of an html element that has been clicked.

This is my code:

```
$(".nav-host-tab").click(function(e){
    alert($(this).html());
    // Try to access the aria-controls attribute of the clicked element
});
```

This is the html context of the `.nav-host-tab` elements:

```
<li id="nav-host-status-tab" role="presentation" class="nav-host-tab active">
    <a href="#host-status" aria-controls="host-status" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Status
    </a>
</li>
```

The statement:

```
alert($(this).html());
```

Returns this html string, where I can clearly see the attribute I'm looking for:

```
<a href="#host-status" aria-controls="host-status" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Status
</a>
```

So I try to access the `aria-controls` attribute with:

```
alert($(this).data('aria-controls'));
```

But it returns:

```
undefined
```

Another try:

```
alert($(this).attr('aria-controls'));
```

And it also returns:

```
undefined
```

How could I access the attribute `aria-controls`?

Comment: `$(this).children().attr('aria-controls');` The HTML shown is of children.

Comment: Try this $('a[href="#host-status"]').attr('aria-controls');

Comment: `this` is not what you think...

Comment: @Tushar — Why `children` instead of `find` ?

Comment: @Rayon In the HTML you can see that it is direct children of `this`. `find` is slower as it has to find in all grand children.

Comment: @Tushar — Makes sense... I personally use `jQuery.find` in all the scenarios.. :)

Comment: @Xar you should post the full html markup specially where is the `.nav-host-tab` class that you hooking your click function. it's little hard to other people understand.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right. I'm sorry I didn't post it originally. I just edited my post. Thank you.

Comment: @mldb you are right. I'm sorry I didn't post it originally. I just edited my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You haven't given us your HTML structure</s>, but if you're seeing it in the HTML returned by `$(this).html()` but `$(this).attr("aria-controls")` doesn't return it, it must be on a descendant element, which you can locate with `find` (and then use `attr` on *that* element):

<s>var controls = $(this).find("a[href='#host-status'][aria-controls]").attr("aria-controls");</s>

Parts of that selector may be optional, depending on the full HTML structure within the `.nav-host-tab`.

Now that you've shown us the structure, it's a child element and in fact the *only* child element, so:

```
var controls = $(this).children().attr("aria-controls");
```

or if you want to be more specific:

```
var controls = $(this).children("a").attr("aria-controls");
```

or

```
var controls = $(this).children("[aria-controls]").attr("aria-controls");
```

etc.

Comment: Why is `find()` better in this situation then `children()` ?

Comment: @Mihailo: Without knowing the OP's overall HTML structure, I was allowing for nesting that wasn't shown. The question should have shown the overall structure so we could provide more specific answers. If the `a` is in fact a direct child, then both `find` and `children` work and `children` will have less work to do. If not, `find` works regardless.

Comment: @Mihailo: OP's shown us the HTML; it *is* a child, so `children` is a good choice.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the child element then get the attribute from that

```
$(".nav-host-tab").click(function(e){
    //find the child element of .nav-host-tab
    var a = $(this).find('a');
    a.attr('aria-controls');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your clicked element doesn't have `aria-controls` so need to find that existed element

```
alert($(this).find("a").attr('aria-controls'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help :)

```js
$(".nav-host-tab").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ariaControls = $(this).find("a[data-toggle=tab]").attr("aria-controls");
    alert(ariaControls);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="nav-host-status-tab" role="presentation" class="nav-host-tab active">
    <a href="#host-status" aria-controls="host-status" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Status
    </a>
</li>
```